the data in the code is properly fetched but also it shows the data as undefined and destructing is also done properly
I'm encountering a TypeError in my React application. The error message is:
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'image' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined. Restro src/components/restroCard.js:5:6 
2 | const { Resdata } = props;
3 | 
4 | const {
5 | image, // Why is this undefined?
6 | title,
7 | category,
8 | price_rating,
View compiled
▶ 14 stack frames were collapsed.

The application was working fine previously, and I haven't made any changes to the code. However, when I tried running it again recently, the website failed to load. The data should contain an 'image' property, so I'm unsure why this error is occurring.
How can I resolve this issue?

Can you post the code you refer. It will help in solving it.
